# redirecting sub sub domains in a wildcard vhost apache (xampp) setup

Tags: apache, xampp, subdomain, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

I am using XAMPP and Acrylic DNS Proxy on Windows 10, and I need to create several apps per day or week, these apps needs sometimes to be served from different domains, I'd like to use subdomains in this cases.

I am trying to serve several apps from an apache folder in domains(app1.jml => c:/apps/app1), so far I got this working.

But I'd like to redirect subdomains to the same domain(sub1.app1.jml => c:/apps/app1) and then let my app(php/mysql) handle the request.

Basically:

```
app1.jml             -> c:/apps/app1    (1)
sub1.app1.jml        -> c:/apps/app1    (2)
sub2.app1.jml        -> c:/apps/app1    (2)

app2.jml             -> c:/apps/app2    (1)
sub1.app2.jml        -> c:/apps/app2    (2)
sub2.app2.jml        -> c:/apps/app2    (2)
```

I got (1) working with the following vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.jml
    VirtualDocumentRoot c:/apps/%1/

    <Directory "c:/sites/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I was not able to get (2). I tried the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.jml
    VirtualDocumentRoot c:/sites/%1/

    <Directory "c:/sites/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.*.jml
    VirtualDocumentRoot c:/sites/%1/

    <Directory "c:/sites/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It did not work, it gave me this:

```
app1.jml             -> c:/apps/app1
sub1.app1.jml        -> c:/apps/sub1
app1.app1.jml        -> c:/apps/app1
```

For `ServerAlias *.*.jml` I tried all (%2, %0, %-1, %-2) in `VirtualDocumentRoot` to no avail.

Am I missing something? 
Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have also posted this answer in the 
[Apache Friends Support Forum](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=78859&p=0&e=0&sid=2a2f7563794144329269c227fa125fa2) and got a reply that my two rules collide, so I fixed the first par of my configuration and removed the second part:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.jml
    VirtualDocumentRoot c:/sites/%-2/

   <Directory "c:/sites/">
      Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What files on xampp did you make this changes?

Comment: @Ikechukwu sorry, I don't remember and I moved to linux since then. But I believe this could go into some vhost config file in apache, and that this vhost file should be loaded by the root configuration.